# CakePHP: How to route Pagination's sort parameters?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

So I'm trying to page items on my index page using the paginator and custom routes.  It's all through the index action, but the index action can show items sorted by newest, votes, active or views.  Right now, the URL looks like this:

```
items/index/sort:created/direction:desc
```

And if you aren't on page one, it looks like this:

```
items/index/sort:created/direction:desc/page:2
```

I'd like to use the router to have it look like this:

```
newest/
```

I can get that far with this route:

```
  Router::connect(
    '/newest/*',
    array('controller'=>'items', 'action'=>'index', 'sort'=>'created', 'direction'=>'desc')
);
```

However, the pager links don't follow the route.  As soon as you click next page, you're back to:

```
items/index/sort:created/direction:desc/page:2
```

How can I make this follow the router and give me what I want?  Keep in mind, it's all from the same controller action, I'm trying to route the sort parameters of pagination basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me your code is working (I've tested your example). Have you done something unusual with the paginator helper?

Here is my Routes:

```
Router::connect('/newest/*',array('controller'=>'tests', 'action'=>'index', 'sort'=>'age', 'direction'=>'desc'));
Router::connect('/oldest/*',array('controller'=>'tests', 'action'=>'index', 'sort'=>'age', 'direction'=>'asc'));
```

And here are the urls which I've seen when I sort by age column:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/1.3.0/newest/page:1
http://localhost/cakephp/1.3.0/newest/page:2
http://localhost/cakephp/1.3.0/newest/page:3
```

And oldest:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/1.3.0/oldest/page:1
http://localhost/cakephp/1.3.0/oldest/page:2
http://localhost/cakephp/1.3.0/oldest/page:3
```

And it's working with all links in the pager (first, prev, 1,2,3 next, last).

Comment: I'm using cakephp 1.3.4, is it possible that this functionality was broken across the versions?

Comment: nope, I've tested with 1.3.0 but then I've tested with 1.3.4 and 1.3.5 and in all cases they were working as expected.

Comment: Weird.  I wonder if something is wrong specifically with my implementation.  This isn't the first time I've run across something that others couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Okay, I updated to 1.3.6 and it fixed it.  I don't know what was going on earlier.  Maybe I screwed something up.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include the passed args I think. Something like this,

```
$this->params = $this->passedArgs();
```

Have a check here also, http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration

Otherwise I would extend the HTML Helper to create my own link method which read in the parameters from the url and created a link accordingly. Then you could manage your own links from your own helper :)

Don't forget that you need to have checks in the index action to deal with this. Personally I would be far more inclined to create an action in the controller for each of these.

```
function newest(){

}
function votes(){

}
function active(){

}

//etc
```

Comment: I believe Daniel was asking for something else: Cake is pretty smart, and if you create a link to a controller/action that has a matching route entry, cake substitutes the url with the route shorthand. But it seems this does not work well for pagination url-s.

Comment: If you create individual actions for those, you just end up duplicating code.